# Ionic 5 - Multiple items in an ion-item dividing the same line

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am migrating a project from version 3.2 to version 5.4 of Ionic and I came across a problem: When I put some items inside an `ion-item`, they divide the line into columns instead of jumping to the next line

```
  <ion-list *ngFor="let ent of ents">
    <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" (click)="selEnt(ent)">
      <h2>{{ ent.nome }}</h2>
      <h3>{{ ent.cidade }} - {{ ent.uf }}</h3>
      <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" slot="end"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

The expected result was

```
xxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyy - zz
```

And the result was

```
xxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyy - zz
```

I tried to use `br/`, `ion-label` and other recurses to do a break line, but no sucess.

How to fix this?

Comment: how about making your ion-item a flex container and no flex wrap, and make your `h2`'s width to 100%

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: im just thinking about this on top of my head. can you create a stackblitz demo so that I could change it there?

Comment: brijmcq, [https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-list-item5] to you see how i want the layout to be. In StackBlitz the error in layout not happens

Answer (score 0):

do you want multiple items in one list? then move your ngFor to ion-item

```
       <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" (click)="selEnt(ent)" *ngFor="let ent of ents">
          <ion-label>
            <h2>{{ ent.nome }}</h2>
            <h3>{{ ent.cidade }} - {{ ent.uf }}</h3>
            <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" slot="end"></ion-icon>
          </ion-label>    
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, simply

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" (click)="selEnt(ent)" *ngFor="let ent of ents">
      <ion-label>
        <h2>{{ ent.nome }}</h2>
        <h3>{{ ent.cidade }} - {{ ent.uf }}</h3>
        <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" slot="end"></ion-icon>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```